# is it possible to change working directory when executing a .py file in different folder?

Tags: python

For example,here is my directory tree:

```
+--- test.py
|
+--- [subdir]
      |
      +--- another.py
```

test.py:

```
import os
os.system('python subdir/another.py')
```

another.py:

```
import os
os.mkdir('whatever')
```

after running test.py ,I expected to have a folder `whatever` in `subdir`,but what I got is:

```
+--- test.py
|
+--- [subdir]
|     |
|     +--- another.py
|
+--- whatever
```

The reason is quite obvious:working directory hadn't been changed to `subdir`.So is it possible to change working directory when executing a .py file in different folder?
Note:

1. any function is allowed, `os.system` is just an example
2. `os.system('cd XXX')` and `os.chdir` not allowed

EDIT:
Finally I decide to use context manager,following an answer in
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17589236/edit

```
import os
import subprocess # just to call an arbitrary command e.g. 'ls'

class cd:
    def __init__(self, newPath):
        self.newPath = newPath

    def __enter__(self):
        self.savedPath = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(self.newPath)

    def __exit__(self, etype, value, traceback):
        os.chdir(self.savedPath)

# Now you can enter the directory like this:
with cd("~/Library"):
   # we are in ~/Library
   subprocess.run("ls")

# outside the context manager we are back where we started.
```

Comment: What about `os.chdir()`?

Comment: If `os.chdir()` is not allowed, why is it allowed to be used in a context manager?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ummm, this is the function to do so: [os.chdir(*path*)](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir).

Maybe it's a little bit confusing or incosistent because function to obtain current working directory is called `os.getcwd()` and has no counterpart setter. Nevertheless, doc says clearly `chdir` changes CWD.

In python 3.x path can be also a valid file descriptor, while in 2.x branch `fchdir(fd)` must be used.

Comment: eh,`os.chdir` can do this...but that's not I want.

Comment: @laike9m You did not say that earlier, and just edited question. Why not? I understand why `os.system('cd xxx')` is disallowed, but you import whole `os` anyway. You also say any function is allowed then you make up arbitrary obstructions lol. Is this an academic question or there are any real reasons behind ?

Comment: The reason is that I have many subdirs,solution not using `os.chdir` will reduce the size of code.

Comment: What? How would it? You **will** need to find out to which dirs you want to get to and execute some code on it anyways. Maybe make a tuple/list of and then use a loop ? I am also confused what you want to achieve but I'm pretty sure it is already out of the question's scope at this point.

Answer (score 5):

You could indeed use `os.chdir` but relying on assumptions about what the current working directory actually is is looking for troubles, and in your case this holds for the `os.system` call in `test.py` as well - try executing `test.py` from anywhere else and you'll find out why.

The safe approach is to derive the current module / script's absolute path from the `__file__` attribute and build absolute path for both the call to `os.system` in `test.py` and the call to `os.mkdir` in `another.py`

To get the absolute path to the current module or script's directory, just use:

```
import os
ABS_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Comment: Well that is not the only troubling point. Using `system("python ...")` is exceptionally bad idea, especially if there are python 2 and 3 installed side by side.

Comment: @luk32 so `subprocess` is better?

Comment: I would personally would look into [`eval/exec`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=eval#eval) or [`importlib`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html). It all depends on what you want to achieve. Problem with executing python externally trough shell it to take that the same version of python is used, so `python3 test.py` works as well as `./test.py` and `python2 test.py`. If you hard-code the command you might accidentally change version. With those method you stay with-in python. It is up to you whether this is desirable.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the `cwd` parameter to [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).`run()`.

`os.system()` is obsolete; the `subprocess` module is much more powerful.

(Edit: Updated for more modern Python, where `run()` is the recommended replacement for `call()`.  Prior to Python 3.5, use `call()`.  Thanks to @zim for pointing out that this answer was out of date).

Comment: You are right,but maybe you should use `popen` instead of `call` cause `call` doesn't seem to support `cwd` argument.

Comment: `call()` accepts exactly the same arguments as `Popen()`.  In fact, it just passes all its arguments to `Popen()`.  (The docs for `call()` are written in a bizarre way, so that's not obvious).

Comment: call() is outdated. use run() instead https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call Despite claims call() DOES NOT accept all the same arguments as Popen(), it does not have any ability to capture output. run() does.